# EditText not getting data consistently android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using a EditText to get user input to create a parking lot object. The edit text is the user input that has all the important info. Then I take that info and add them to cloudmine database. But the Edit text does not parse consistently the inputs. I check it on cloudmine and it often shows up as null. Do not know why?

Here is the code snippet

```
private String name;
private String address;
private String pricing;
private String hours;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//calling parent constructor
    setContentView(R.layout.addparking_layout);//setting up the GUI

    findViewById(R.id.LotName).setOnKeyListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.LotAddress).setOnKeyListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.LotPricing).setOnKeyListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.LotHours).setOnKeyListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.LotLat).setOnKeyListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.LotLon).setOnKeyListener(this);

}

public void addParkingLot(View v)
{
    new createCloudmineLot().execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Inside the onKey method");
    EditText temp = (EditText) v;
    System.out.println("Text: "+ temp.getText());
    //getting the text for the appropriate info
    if(temp.getId() == R.id.LotName)
    {
        name = "" + temp.getText();
        System.out.println("name: "+name);
    }
    else
        if(temp.getId() == R.id.LotAddress)
        {
            address = "" + temp.getText();
            System.out.println("address: "+ address);
        }
        else
            if(temp.getId() == R.id.LotPricing)
            {
                pricing = "" + temp.getText();
                System.out.println("pricing: "+pricing);
            }
            else
                if(temp.getId() == R.id.LotHours)
                {
                    hours = "" + temp.getText();
                    System.out.println("hours: "+hours);
                }
                else
                    if(temp.getId() == R.id.LotLat)
                    {
                        latitude = "" + temp.getText();
                        System.out.println("latitude: "+latitude);
                    }
                    else
                        if(temp.getId() == R.id.LotLon)
                        {
                            longitude = "" + temp.getText();
                                System.out.println("longitude: "+longitude);
                        }

    return false;
}

public class createCloudmineLot extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    private boolean success = false;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         CMApiCredentials.initialize(APP_ID, API_KEY,  getApplicationContext());//initializing Cloudmine connetion
         SimpleCMObject parkingLot = new SimpleCMObject();

         parkingLot.add("name", name);
         parkingLot.add("address",address);
         parkingLot.add("pricing",pricing);
         parkingLot.add("hours",hours);
         parkingLot.add("latitude",latitude);
         parkingLot.add("longitude",longitude);

         parkingLot.save(new ObjectModificationResponseCallback() 
         {
                public void onCompletion(ObjectModificationResponse response) 
                {
                    success = response.wasSuccess();
                    Toast.makeText(AddParking.this, "Parking Lot was added:" + success,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
         });

        return null;
    }//end of doBackground

}//end on AsyncTask

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I want to point out with your code that may be a problem. While it is not a concrete answer, I think it will approach your problem and help you resolve it. One of them might even be the main problem.

First consider your 'onKey' method. What key are you reacting to? You are not processing the 'event' or the 'keyCode'. The method will be invoked on all key presses, letters included. I suspect that the 'null' values come from users pushing any non character key.

What I propose is that you alter your code to react to, for example, only the enter key

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

Now you can be sure that the user hit the enter key which usually means he input something meaningful.

I would also advise to reduce the complexity of your code. It is quite hard to read. I would advise using a 'switch' statement.

```
switch(temp.getId())
{    
    case(R.id.LotName):
        // Your code here
        break;
    case(R.id.nextEditTextID):
        // etc
}
```

This will make your code easier to read and less likely you make an error.